# Recursive Wildcards in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, wildcard

I'm trying to delete files in a specific set of folders with PowerShell. My code currently looks like this:

```
$tempfolders = @(
    "C:\Windows\Temp\*"
    "C:\Documents and Settings\*\Local Settings\temp\*"
    "C:\Users\*\Appdata\Local\Temp\*"
    )

Remove-Item $tempfolders -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

I want to add a new folder to that list, with the following formula:

```
"C:\users\*\AppData\Local\Program\**\Subfolder"
```

where `**` could be multiple subfolders of unknown length. For example, it could be `settings\subsettings` or it could be `folder\settings\subsettings`. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You might have to use `Get-ChildItem` to get the contents of a main folder, then filter what matches your criteria, then delete those results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can feed the full path of each file to a regex; this will return only the files that match your format, which you can then pipe to Remove-Item:

```
ls "C:\Users" -Recurse -Hidden | Where-Object { $_.FullName -imatch '^C:\\users\\([^\\]+)\\AppData\\Local\\Program\\(.*)\\Subfolder' }
```

Because regexes are considered write-only, a bit of explanation:

- backslashes count as escape characters inside a regex and need to be doubled.
- `([^\\]+)` means one or more of any character except a backslash
- `.*` means zero or more of any character

Comment: For some reason that's not working, even though I know it should. It's not finding the files. I put it into a regex tester online, and it should be finding the files, but when I put it into the PowerShell command it returns nothing.

Comment: Figured it out. I had to point ls to a starting point, so that it runs in the right area of the file system, and include the -hidden flag since the appdata folder is hidden. (Although, this increased the run time of the script immensely.) I edited the answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse`,
This will do exactly what you are asking for. Pipe it from the array to a `Remove-Item`

```
@("C:\Windows\Temp\*", "C:\Documents and Settings\*\Local Settings\temp\*", "C:\Users\*\Appdata\Local\Temp\*") | 
    Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
    Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Just for a heads up in Powershell Piping `|` is key. PowerShell we love to chain commands.

Comment: This is literally my code, with a minor edit, and doesn't even attempt to answer the question at hand.